# Indefinite Integral: $\int{x\cos{(x+1)}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following indefinite integral:

$$\int{x\cos{(x+1)}}dx$$

But I keep running into problems as I am thinking of solving it using parts in which I did the following:

$$
u = x+1 \\
du = 1\ dx \\
\int{x\cos{(x+1)}}dx = \int{x\cos{u}}du
$$

Then from $u = x+1$ I get $x = u-1$ then:

$$\int{x\cos{u}}du = \int{(u-1)\cos{u}}du$$

Which appears that I am doing something really wrong. How do I proceed?

Comment: Why do you say that? What appears wrong?

Comment: Partial integral would be work. You can try it by using the formula of partial integral

Comment: @Kaynex because it appears that I would continuously be having to substitute.

Comment: @akusaja What formula is that?

Comment: Dr sonnhard already provided the answer. You can check it. The formula is if u= x and du=dx, then dv= cos (x+1) dx,  so v= sin(x+1), so the integral can be converted to: uv - int v du. That's the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set $$u=x$$ and $$v'=\cos(x+1)$$ then we get $$u'=1$$ and $$v=\sin(x+1)$$
and we get $$x\sin(x+1)-\int\sin(x+1)dx=\cos(x+1)+x\sin(x+1)+C$$

Comment: Wouldn't $v=\sin(x+1)$?

Comment: yes you are right, i just corrected it Omari

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts:

$\int (u-1)\cos u du=\int (u-1)d \sin u= (u-1)\sin u - \int \sin u d(u-1)$

$=(u-1)\sin u -\int \sin u du=(u-1)\sin u + \cos u$.

Comment: and a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your substitution is correct: the easiest way of proceeding with your method is to notice that  $\int{(u-1)\cos{u}}\;du$ can be divided into two integrals

$$\int{(u-1)\cos{u}}\;du=\int u\cos{u}\;du-\int{\cos{u}}\;du$$

The first integral of the two can be found by integrating by parts

$$\int u\cos{u}\;du=u\sin u-\int \sin u\;du$$

Therefore using your method proceeds as

$$\int{(u-1)\cos{u}}\;du=u\sin u-\int \sin u\;du-\int{\cos{u}}\;du$$

which becomes

$$\int{(u-1)\cos{u}}\;du=u\sin u+ \cos u-\sin{u}+C$$